# Infinite Loop x Counter Problems

Tags: debugging, python-3.x, logic, counter, infinite-loop

Hello I have three problems with my code:

1. when I type in "N" for my first question, it goes into an error.
2. I get in an infinite loop after the "Run again?" input.
3. my counters do not add up properly so even when I get an answer right or wrong, it doesn't count them.

Please help me.

Below is my code:

```
    #Introduction-ish print statement
print("In this application, we will be playing a coin coss game.  For as "\
      "many times as you like, we will continue playing the game.")


#def function1():
response=str(input("\nWould you like to run this application?  Type 'Y' to run "\
               "or 'N' to not run: "))
if response=="N":
    print("\nOutcome of Game:")
    print("You did not run the application."\
          "  Nothing happened.  You did not play the game.")


#Counters
programCounter=0
hCounter=0
tCounter=0
guessCountR=0
guessCountW=0

#User Input

if response=="Y":

    funcGuess=str(input("\nPick one- Type 'H' for Heads or 'T' for Tails: "))

#Coins

import random

#number=random.randint(1,2)

while response !="N" and funcGuess=="H" or funcGuess=="T":
    number=random.randint(1,2)
    if number==1:
        number=="Heads"
        hCounter+=1
    else:
            number=="Tails"
            tCounter+=1
    if funcGuess==number:
        guessCountR+=1
    else:
        guessCountW+=1

    print(number)
    response=str(input("Run again?"))
    if response=="Y":
        funcGuess=str(input("\nPick one- Type 'H' for Heads or 'T' for Tails: "))
if response=="N":
    print("\nOutcome of Game:")
    print("You guessed ",programCounter, "time(s).")
    print("You guessed heads",hCounter, "time(s).")
    print("You guessed tails",tCounter, "time(s).")
    print("You guessed correctly",guessCountR, "time(s).")
    print("You guessed incorrectly",guessCountW, "time(s).")

#Guess Count
guessCount=guessCountR+guessCountW


#paste


#if response =="Y":
    #function1()

#else:
    #print("\nOutcome of Game:")
    #print("You did not run the application."\
          #"  Nothing happened.  You did not play the game.")
```

I don't mind all the comments.  I purposely left them there but if anyone helping finds them useful, please let me know.

Apologies in advanced for the long post.

Comment: Please create a minimal example for each problem and re-submit them as separate questions.

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1:

On line 34 you're evaluating a variable called `funcGuess`. It only gets defined on line 26 should you answer 'Y' to the initial question.

Problem 2:

The while loop loops infinitely, because break conditions can never be met. There's no way to assign `response` the value "N" within the loop. Also, be sure to put both sides of the `or` evaluation between parentheses in order to evaluate the line correctly

Problem 3:

The correct number and the guess are assigned into variables `number` and `funcGuess`, respectively. `number` is always 1 or 2, and `funcGuess` is always "H" or "T". Therefore `funcGuess == number` can never evaluate as `True`.